# Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 freeze xcode and app when print XML (NSLog)

Tags: objective-c, xml, nslog, xcode4.4, llvm-4.0

I update for xcode 4.4 (with Apple LLVM compiler 4.0) and since then when i try to print XML in console the xcode and app (in simulator) block user interaction...and i need wait 30seconds or more until finish (i can't do nothing)

i´m using AFNetworking and TBXML, but the problem isn't in parse because if i remove the parse the problem continue.

So i try NSOperationQueue,NSBlockOperation, grand dispatch central ... and nothing, still freeze.

Is because XML is too big??? (...i need print XML to debug and test things)

**1º The Request and print XML**

```
- (void) doRequestPOST:(NSString*)URL params:(NSString*)params withSuccess:(void(^)(BOOL,id))successBlock{

(....)

AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [sharedAPI HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            NSString* xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            //>>>>>PROBLEM HERE<<<<< if i remove next line (nslog) the problem does not occur
            NSLog(@"\n\nResponse \nURL :\n%@\nXML :\n%@\n \n",operation.request.URL,xml);
            [xml release];

            TBXML * tbxml = [TBXML newTBXMLWithXMLData:responseObject error:nil];
            [self saveCookiesFromHTTPHeaderFields:[operation response] withTBXML:tbxml.rootXMLElement];

            if (successBlock) {
                successBlock(TRUE,responseObject);
            }
}
```

**2º Will ask for request and parse**
response from "successBlock(TRUE,responseObject);"

```
[self doRequestPOST:stringURL params:nil withSuccess:^(BOOL success, id response) {

        if (success) {

            //will parse response

            [self.dictionaryCategoryContents setObject:[Parser parseVodContent:response] forKey:idCategory];
            if (responseBlock){
                responseBlock (YES,[dictionaryCategoryContents objectForKey:idCategory]);
            }

        }else {

            if (responseBlock){
                responseBlock (NO,response);
            }
        }
    }];
```

Comment: How big is the XML?  (log `[responseObject length]`).

Comment: [responseObject length] 44419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to be fixed by 4.4.1 released on 8/7/2012.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently encountering the same problem.  Whenever I NSLog a large string, I just see XCode and the Simulator hang (beachball).  But if I wait 2-3 minutes, the app will proceed.

There seems to be a bug with XCode 4.4, and other devs reported the same behavior:
http://openradar.appspot.com/11972490

Answer (score 1):

If you need to *log* the response for debugging (or error reporting) then I think you should write the `responseObject` to a file in the caches directory (or whatever the equivalent folder is under iOS, if that is the O/S).  Then you can access this file to see what the response was.  The only problem to overcome then is how to keep the folder from getting too big; perhaps delete all previously written files when the app starts or at regular intervals.

You can write the response using the `[NSData writeToURL:atomically:]` method and this will be quicker as it doesn't require conversion to string first.

Comment: didn't work :( , i already try writeToURL or writeToFile.. load with stringWithContentsOfURL, and the problem continue

Comment: You mean it still freezes when you write the `responseObject` without converting it to a string?

Comment: hum... probably i'm doing wrong, so i define a path to URL and write [dataXML writeToURL:storeUrl atomically:YES] after i load with [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:storeUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error] or [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:storeUrl] but still freezes in both ways

Comment: And if you remove **all** logging of the XML, the freezing goes away?  I'm wondering if it's the actual loading of the data across the network...

Comment: Yes, if i remove all nslog goes away